# No Appropriate protocols

Tags: java, spring, email, jax-rs, protocols

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate); message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)] with root cause

`Try to change Services option.
Try to change Application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.mail.password=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false`
```

Comment: This means that either the client or server is using either an SSL / TLS version that is old and insecure or a cypher suite that is deprecated.   Start by rerunning with the option `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and then read the debug logging to figure out what the incompatibility.

Comment: Depending on which side is older, the solution may be to upgrade your client side JVM to something more recent, or set some additional options or properties to force the client side to use a different (older) protocol version and/or ciphers.  The former approach is better.  The latter is potentially reducing security.